# Automatically redirect from one JSP page to Another

Tags: java, jsp

Is it possible to redirect a user automatically to a second jsp page as soon as the home page loads?

Comment: That wouldn't be done by the JSP. That is server side. You want client side behavior. Use javascript. I don't see the point however. Wouldn't you just want to send a redirect instead of ever hitting the first page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an example of such a thing:
[JSP - Page Redirecting](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_page_redirect.htm)

Simplest is using `sendRedirect`:

```
public void response.sendRedirect(String location)
throws IOException
```

Comment: Whilst this is the accepted answer, you should try hard to minimise the amount of scriptlets in your JSP as they inevitably add untestable complexity. If you need a tutorial which achieves the same thing using standard tag libraries see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_redirect_tag.htm

Answer (score 28):

With core JSTL libraries loaded `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>` you can use:

```
<c:redirect url="/home.html"/>
```

Comment: can I see it being implemented somewhere?

Comment: Sure, all over the place. Did you look? Here is an example http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/jsp/jstl/CoreTagRedirect.html and another http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_redirect_tag.htm and some notes from IBM http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jstl0318/