# how to redirect to a jsp page from a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

well 
I have a jsp page with a login form, i'm using a servlet, if the username and password are correct the servlet redirects the user to another page else it redirects him to the login page again

when i log in with a correct username and password i'm redirected perfectly to reservation.jsp but when i put a wrong username or password in the form when i click on the submit button the page became blank

here is the servlet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LogServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/LogServlet")
public class LogServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;




public LogServlet() {
    super();

}



protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.setContentType("text/html");


    String name=request.getParameter("name");
    String password=request.getParameter("password");

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/log",
                "root","");
        ps = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("select nom_client,username,password from client where username = ? and password = ?");

        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, password);
        rs=ps.executeQuery();



    try {
        while(rs.next()){
        if(password.equals(rs.getString("password")) && name.equals(rs.getString("username"))){

        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("name",name);
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        request.getRequestDispatcher("reservation.jsp").include(request, response);
        }
        else{
            response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");

        }}
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    System.out.close();


    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}


}
}
```

Comment: Check this if this might be helpful to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576159/automatically-redirect-from-one-jsp-page-to-another

Comment: In addition, you should not to nest try catch blocks

Answer (score 2):

use `request.getContextPath()`, It will redirect you to login page.

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/login.jsp");
```

and if you are reaching to your login page in that case, pass `request` and `response` objects to your jsp page.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath()+"/login.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

As you have used

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("reservation.jsp").include(request, response);
```

to forward after successful login and as it is working, why not forwarding after failed also in this way .?

Which mean to use

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").include(request, response);
```

Comment: please be careful about the location of your login.jsp location. see if it is in the right location where in should be.

Comment: i have all the jsp files in the same location..i have tested your suggestion in another projet and it works perfectly, but not with that one

Comment: try removing the slash `/` use  `request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").include(request, response); `   or    `request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request,response);`

Comment: the problem still persists

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be here:

response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");

This means that in the location header of the redirect response you will have:

http://localhost:8080/login.jsp

If you change it to:

response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");

than its relative to your webabb context path:

http://localhost:8080/app/login.jsp

Try with firebug or similar and trace down request/response you should find out quickly. And be sure jsp files are were expected in the hierarchy.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").include(request, response);
```

Have u tried above code in else part ? 
I think it should work

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `response.sendRedirect(...)` does not prepend the context path where the resource (jsp) is bundled.
Try using `request.getRequestDispatcher(...)` in both cases.

Comment: which url are you redirected to?

Comment: i'm not redirected at all
in the browser a have the name of the servlet. but the page is blank

Comment: What username and password aye you submitting? ¿Have you tried removing `while(rs.next()){` block?

Comment: while(rs.next()){
i used it to compare the username and password with the data selected from the database

Comment: when i remove it, even the fisrt redirect don't work

Answer (score 0):

Rather than giving
            response.sendRedirect("\login.jsp");
use         response.sendRedirect("/yourprojectname/");
and in welcome file in web.xml set login.jsp as welcome file.

Answer (score -1):

Add this

```
response.sendRedirect("/yourprojectname/");
```

and set login.jsp as welcome file in web.xml

Comment: response.sendRedirect("yourJsp Page");

Answer (score -1):

The response from the database was empty, so I had to add that case to the class (via `if/else` condition).

Comment: In that case, just post an answer, if you think it will be helpful for others.