# How to get parameter "par" from link app/page/par in a servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, get

I have some app, where a user going to link like "..app/page/par", should be redirected to page "..app/page" and then on it page should be add some data, that I should get using parameter "par"

How can I do it, using java servlets?

Comment: Visit this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967482/redirect-pages-in-jsp

Answer (score 0):

The session scope can be used to store the parameter value on the server side between the two requests.

Request 1
app/page/par

```
String parameterValue = request.getParameter("par");
request.getSession().setAttribute("par", parameterValue);
response.sendRedirect("app/page");
```

Request 2
app/page

```
// pass the value to the view
request.setAttribute("viewAttributeName", request.getSession().getAttribute("par"));
```