# I keep getting a status 500 error but my code seems to be correct, any solution?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, netbeans

I have a simple code for an admin to log in on a JSP page, the code ran perfectly however now I keep getting this status 500 error and am unsure how to fix it.

```
<%

String adminusername = request.getParameter("adminusername");
String adminpass = request.getParameter("adminpass");
String adminconfpass = request.getParameter("adminconfpass");
          
//if statement to meet certain criteria before allowing access

if (adminusername.equals("clubadmin") && adminpass.equals("123") && adminconfpass.equals("123"))
        {
            
            //if criteria is met redirects admin to the admin home page
            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967482/redirect-pages-in-jsp utilized for this code
            
           String redirectURL = "http://localhost:8080/SportClubLotteryFYP/adminhome.jsp";
           response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
        }
else {
    
           String redirectURL = "http://localhost:8080/SportClubLotteryFYP/adminlogin.jsp";
           response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
           
        }




%>
```

It keeps telling me that I have an error at line 9 which is the start of the if statement but I see nothing wrong with the code. I am using Netbeans and Tomcat. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read the tomcat log to get the exception raised by your server. Is it an NPE ?

Comment: The log says the root cause is: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You can check if adminusername, adminpass and adminconfpass are not null.
You can also rewrite your test to bypass the NPE :   
if (("clubadmin".equals(adminusername) && "123".equals(adminpass) && "123".equals(adminconfpass))

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin thank you that solved it!