# post empty when php file is not specified

Tags: php, post

If i dont specify php file when i call url, $_POST is empty.
For example:

with this code:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
```

if i call like this(with some post params): `http://domain.com/api.json`
response is:

```
array(0) {
}
```

If i call like this: `http://domain.com/api.json/index.php`

```
array(1) {
  ["param"]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

I assume that it is something with the server configuration, but i dont know exactly what
I want to be able to not specify php file in my api calls

**EDIT:**
Response Headers:

```
Connection → Keep-Alive  
Content-Encoding → gzip  
Content-Length → 92  
Content-Type → application/json, text/html  
Date → Sun, 22 Feb 2015 12:19:03 GMT  
Keep-Alive → timeout=5, max=99  
Server → Apache  
Vary → Accept-Encoding  
X-Powered-By → PleskLin
```

Comment: What are the HTTP headers that you receive from `http://domain.com/api.json`?

Comment: Added headers in question. If i specify index.php, headers are the same

Comment: "i dont know exactly what i want to be able", you should..

Comment: I was thinking that the user agent [might change the HTTP method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068418/whats-the-difference-between-a-302-and-a-307-redirect) if the original response contained a `Location` header. If this is not the case, how is your server configured to execute the PHP script? Apache's `LocationMatch` or something similar?

Comment: @tsnorri I honestly have no idea, im using plesk, how can i check that?