# How redirect with args for view function without query string on Flask?

Tags: python, flask, http-redirect

I want to redirect users to same path but with different arguments.

Here's my code:

```
@app.route('/foo')
def foo(args1=None, args2=None):
    return render_template('foo.html', args1=args1, args2=args2)

@app.route('/bar')
def redirect_to_foo():
    return redirect(url_for('foo', args1='something'))
```

But when I see url path, that shows `/foo?arg1=something...` .
How redirect with args but without query string?
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: See related http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect. HTML has no POST redirect. If you will implement it with Status-Code 307 the user will get a prompt. Another way would be to save arguments in a session before sending 301-redirect code.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068418/whats-the-difference-between-a-302-and-a-307-redirect.

Answer (score 1):

In HTTP 1.1, there actually is a [status code (307)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) which indicates that the request should be repeated using the same method and post data. Try to use HTTP status code `307 Internal Redirect` instead of `302`. For flask there is a parameter [code](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.redirect).

```
@app.route('/bar', methods=['POST'])
def redirect_to_foo():
    return redirect(url_for('foo', args1='something'), code=307)
```

Source: [Redirecting to URL in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343812/redirecting-to-url-in-flask)

And as a background also have a look in my comments in OP.

Hint: Maybe it's not the right I answer. I didn't understand why you want to redirect with different arguments. Sending back "different arguments" as a HTTP payload beside an redirect header is AFAIK (except for GET/"in query string") not possible. If you really have to do it, think about the structure.

Comment: Thanks. I tried 307 redirect but the url redirected is still `/foo?args=something` .

Comment: @Jonycruse It will work. Your initial request also have to be a POST request.