# Symfony2: Sending arbitrary POST data from Controller

Tags: php, symfony, post, controller

In the Controller, I would like to use :

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('bissap_forum_topic', [
        'request' => $request
    ], 307);
```

But i need to pass some parameters for route *bissap_forum_topic*

```
bissap_forum_topic:
    path:     /topic/{topic_id}/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: BISSAPForumBundle:F:topic, page:1 }
```

Is it possible to rededirect a Route with POST method and some parameters?

Comment: Status 307 is not what you are looking for. 307 indicates to the user-agent that the request-method should not be changed.

So for example if a you request a page with POST and some-data and the server responds with 307 then the browser will issue the same POST-request with the same Data as before to the redirect-url. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068418/whats-the-difference-between-a-302-and-a-307-redirect)

Comment: @gries Ok..But, have you got a proposal for my issue?

Comment: You could use something like guzzle to issue a post-request and then redirect with 302 to the resource you would like to display.