# response.sendRedirect shows unwanted HttpStatus 302 instead of 307

Tags: java, redirect, httpresponse, http-status-code-302, http-status-code-307

I have a small test, which should return a HttpStatus with Temporary Redirect with HttpStatus Code 307.
But it always returns a 302.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class Controller {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT ) 
    @RequestMapping(value= "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void resolveUrl(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
        response.sendRedirect("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

When I look into the documentation of `response.sendRedirect()` I can read this:

> Sends a temporary redirect response to the client using the specified
>        * redirect location URL.

and the [documentation of temporary redirect is a 307](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> 10.3.8 307 Temporary Redirect
>
> The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI.
>   Since the redirection MAY be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD
>   continue to use the Request-URI for future requests. This response is
>   only cacheable if indicated by a Cache-Control or Expires header
>   field.

(I know, that I don't need the `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT)` or the `response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);` but I want to show that it will not work with this things too!)

But my test shows that it was a 302 and not a 307

> java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<307> but was:<302>

Can somebody explain this?

My small test for this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = get("/test");
        mvc.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(status().isTemporaryRedirect())
                .andExpect(redirectedUrl("https://www.google.com"));
    }

}
```

[Complete code can be found at github](https://github.com/joergi/temporalymoved)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068418/whats-the-difference-between-a-302-and-a-307-redirect

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `sendRedirect`, set the `Location` header in the `response` object like so:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
response.setHeader("Location","https://we.google.com");
```