# Not able to perform redirection using POST method

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to perform one redirection using Apache Camel, but I'm not able to do this, because every time it's showing me GET method, but I have to redirect using POST method.

```
public void redirectFromSuccess(Exchange exchange) {
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", "POST");
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("Location","http://testURL.com/SuccessURL");
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE,"301");

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a 302 and a 307 redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068418/whats-the-difference-between-a-302-and-a-307-redirect)

Comment: Can you please add your route?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set method as follows:
exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", "POST");

Comment: yeah actually i tried with "POST" only but its not work ..its calling GET method only

Answer (score 0):

**Try in this way :**

```
public void redirectFromSuccess(Exchange exchange) {
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST")); 
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI,"http://testURL.com/SuccessURL");
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE,"301");

}
```

Here is another very simple example :

```
from("direct:start")
 .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
 .to("http://www.google.co.in");
```